# How to use if else statement correctly?

Tags: php

I want check, whether booking id is not in the database as well as it is greater than today. The database checking part working. But this part not going through if the condition is true. I think something wrong with the `if` `else` statements.

```
else if($checkindate > $today)
{
    $bidErr="This booking is not comming today. Please check again";
}
```

I have include full code here. booking Id `bid` coming from a form.

```
<?php
    $today=date("Y-n-j"); 
    echo "<h4>Today is <font color='red'>".$today."</font></h4><br><br>";
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $bidErr =  "";
    $bid =  "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $flag = 1;
        if (empty($_POST["bid"])) {
            $bidErr = "Booking ID is required.";
            $flag=0;
        } else {
            $bid = test_input($_POST["bid"]);
            // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
            if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/",$bid)) {
                $bidErr = "Only Numbers are allowed"; 
                $flag=0;
            }
        }
        include("connect.php");
        if($flag=="1"){
            $SQL="SELECT guestid,checkindate FROM bookings WHERE bookingid='$bid'";
            $run=mysql_query($SQL,$con) or die ("SQL error");
            $rec=mysql_fetch_array($run);
            $row=mysql_num_rows($run);

            $checkindate = $rec['checkindate'];

            echo $checkindate;

            if ($row < 1) {
                $bidErr="Invalid BookingID. Please check again";
            }   
            else if($checkindate > $today) {
                $bidErr="This booking is not comming today. Please check again";
            } else {
                $_SESSION["chinbid"] = $bid ;
                header("Location: checkinhandler.php");
                exit;
            }
        }
    }

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
?>
```

Comment: where have u taken `$_POST["bid"]` as `$bid`?

Comment: You shouldn't use any mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since php 5.5 and completely removed in php 7.0

Comment: try  `elseif` instead of `else if`

Comment: Not working whether elseif or else if

Comment: upcoming bookingIds can be checked in now. It shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `$checkindate` is same as `$today` date.

Try to check `$checkindate` format is like `date("Y-m-d")` (2016-09-16). IF so then `$today` will be like

```
$today=date("Y-m-d");
```

Check the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Also i suggest to go for mysqli_* instead of using mysql_*. Because It has been deprecated since php 5.5 and completely removed in php 7.0 .

Comment: Thanks. i'll check

Comment: IT works.. This is the case $today=date("Y-n-j"); 
  and checkindate format is ("Y-m-d"); Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
else if(date("Y-n-j", strtotime($checkindate)) > $today)
```

I'm guessing your `$checkindate` is not in the same format (Y-n-j) as your `$today` variable.

Comment: Thank you. date format error as you said. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$row='0';
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$date=date_create("2016-09-15");
$today = date("Ymd"); 
$date= date_format($date, 'Ymd');
echo "Checkin date is " . $date. "<br>";
echo "Today is " . $today."<br>";
if ($row < '1'){
    echo "no records";
} elseif ($date == $today) {
    echo "dates are the same";
} else {
    echo "check in handler";
}
?>
```